# image:{minWidth:500} is not working in fineuploader

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using Jcrop fineuploader for cropping image. I have to validate minimum width of image. I'm using like below

```
validation: {
   allowedExtensions: ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif'],
   image : {minWidth:500}
}
```

unfortunately this is not working. What wrong here I did ?

Comment: Which browser? What type of image? Which version of Fine Uploader?

Comment: Fine uploader 3.0 version.. All Browsers. Jpeg / png etc,.

Answer (score 0):

Image validation is not supported in Fine Uploader 3.0. Support for image validation wasn't added until [version 4.1](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/11/25/fine-uploader-4-1-pause-uploads-image-validation-support-for-more-browsers/), which itself is several years old. Consider upgrading to a recent version (5.6 was just released).